# How to access values of predict() function in R for storage?

Tags: r, vector, data-science, knn

I'm training a K-nearest neighbors model for a class. The catch is that they ask us to train it with the **whole** database, **except** for the row being predicted.

My plan is to initialize a vector for storage and run a for loop to loop over every row omitting that specific row for training, then appending the prediction value to the vector, and calculating accuracy after the loop:

```
results <- c()
for (i in nrow(data) {
        model.kknn <- train.kknn(data[-i,11]~., data = data[-i,1:10],kmax = 7, scale = TRUE)
        pred <- predict(model,data[i,1:10])
        results <- c(results,pred)
}
```

I'm expecting the vector `results` to be a series of 1s and 0s. However, I tried looping just the first row and the value of `results` is `2`.

When printing `pred` the value is:

```
[1] 1

Levels: 0 1
```

Any idea how I can get the 1 to append to the vector `results`?

Comment: I havent looked too deep into this, but it seems like your for loop should be : for ( i in 1:nrow(data) ).    nrow(data) is just a vector of length = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `1:N` in the for() part, and it's best not to "grow" a vector but rather to initialize an empty vector of the appropriate length and fill it in.

```
N <- nrow(data)
results <- vector(length=N)
for (i in 1:N) {
        model.knn <- train.kknn(data[-i,11]~., data=data[-i,1:10], kmax=7, scale=T)
        results[i] <- predict(model.knn, data[i,1:10,drop=F])
}
```